# Allow the user to access the UIButton only once a day (Considering time zone)

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to allow the user to execute some code inside the action of a UIButton only once day. How can it be implemented? I found NSTimer unsuitable for this purpose.

Comment: Store last use date. Check if it's previous day. Allow/Disallow accordingly, you can use a NSTimer to check again each minutes, or program the allowance.

Comment: @Larme But using device date not safe as user can change device date from settings.

Comment: You cannot trust user data. Period. I'd say this is the wrong approach to secure your ressources anyway - but if it still is, you probably need to contact a web service for a valid time stamp and render that function useless if offline. And don't forget - things you store on your device might get tinkered with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefaults like this

```
-(void)btnPressed:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];

    df.dateFormat = @"d/m/yyyy";

    NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    if ([pref boolForKey:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]) {
        // do nothing button is used
    }else{
        [pref setBool:YES forKey:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

        // do the daily operartion for one time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NSTimer is bad idea because if your app gets killed by the user it won't have same timer on restart. You probably want to save last accessed date, and than compare date now with last access date, similar to this:

Swift

```
//store lastAccessDate somewhere in your system NSUserDefaults for example
var lastAccessDate:NSDate!

//on button click or other action get today's date and compare to lastAccessDate
let newAccessDate = NSDate()
if (newAccessDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastAccessDate)/1000.0 > 24*60*60) {
    //do something here
    lastAccessDate = newAccessDate
}
```

Objective-C

```
//store lastAccessDate somewhere in your system NSUserDefaults for example
NSDate *lastAccessDate;

//on button click or other action get today's date and compare to lastAccessDate
NSDate *newAccessDate = [NSDate date];
if ([newAccessDate timeIntervalSinceDate:lastAccessDate]/1000.0 > 24*60*60) {
    //do something here
    lastAccessDate = newAccessDate;
}
```

Comment: Using Objective c, but yes NSTimer is not useful here.

Comment: You didn't mention programming language in your question or tags. In Objective-C code looks really similar, I've updated my answer for both languages.

Comment: what is this line doing  "if ([newAccessDate timeIntervalSinceDate:lastAccessDate]/1000.0 > 7*24*60*60)"

Comment: timeIntervalSinceDate returns result in milliseconds so we convert it to seconds, and than compare it with seconds count in 24 hours (sorry, got mistake, haven't deleted 7). So if seconds passed more than 24(hours)*60(minutes)*60(seconds) than it's a new day and we can allow user to do stuff, otherwise not.

Comment: @NSDmitry `timeIntervalSinceDate:` returns seconds, not milliseconds. And if may be better to use NSDateComponents.

Comment: @Larme NSDateComponents is another object to create, also you'll need NSCalendar also, it creates a bit more complicated problem than it is right now, so if the problem that simple, I prefer simple solution.

Comment: @NSDmitry: It's just that I understood (the OP wasn't clear in his question), that "once a day" means each 24+ hours or each day.

Comment: @NSDmitry Once a day as i understood means, only one time in a day. So, user can access the button only one time in a day. i don't understand what is not clear anyway thanks.

Comment: @Larme I found your approach best to use NSCalendar, it solved my problem easily with short code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *lastAccessDate;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss a"];

lastAccessDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[arrList valueForKey:@"LastUpdatedDate"]];

//    //on button click or other action get today's date and compare to lastAccessDate
NSDate *newAccessDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[arrList valueForKey:@"CurrentTime"]];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *componentsForFirstDate = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:lastAccessDate];

NSDateComponents *componentsForSecondDate = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:newAccessDate];

if ([componentsForFirstDate day] != [componentsForSecondDate day])
```